# CookieStore.add returns NPE even for non-null values of uri and cookie?

Tags: java, cookies, nullpointerexception

For some reason trying to add a cookie returns a null pointer exception, even when the URI and cookie values are not null. Here's the complete code, following the content of the Apache Harmony "CookieStoreTest.java":

```
package junk;

import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class CookieProblem {

    private static CookieStore cookieStore;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = new URI("http://harmony.test.unit.org");
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("name1", "value1");
        cookie.setDiscard(true);
        System.out.println(cookie.toString() + " - " + uri.toString());
        cookieStore.add(uri, cookie);
    }
}
```

When I run it I see that the Cookie and URI values are definitely present, but I still get an NPE:

```
name1="value1" - http://harmony.test.unit.org
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at junk.CookieProblem.main(CookieProblem.java:16)
```

I've tried this in Java 6 and Java 7 on Mac OSX 10.8.5 with the same results. I've tried with/without the discard option, with/without setting domain, maxAge, path and value separately... same result.

Am I just managing to use two specific versions of Java (1.7.0_55-b13 and 1.6.0_51_b11) that both have this issue on OSX? Or am I overlooking something horribly obvious and really need to drink my coffee this morning? I'm hoping it's the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CookieStore` is null. Seriously, get that coffee and quick.

Comment: Head, meet desk. I simplified the code so far down from the original scenario I was having issues with that I completely ignored the fact that I was no longer getting an existing cookie store from my HTTP client. Coffee, here I come.